# How do I calculate the number of paths taken to move from the first index to the last index in a 2D array?

Tags: python, dynamic-programming

The question is that you have to calculate the number of ways you can travel from the first index to the last index in a 2D array, here 0 means that you can enter the house, and 1 means you can't. You can only move horizontally or vertically.

---

**Sample input:**

```
                  [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                   [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
                   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],    
                   [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
                   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                   [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
                   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                   [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
                   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

**Sample output:**     `8512`

---

I've used the concept of dynamic programming to find the solution. This is my code:

```
N=int(input())
maze=[]
for i in range(N):
    X=input().split(" ",N)
    for j in range(N):
        X[j]=int(X[j])
    maze.append(X)

#base condition
for i in range(N):
    if maze[i][0]==0:
        maze[i][0]=1
    else:
        break

for i in range(1,N):
    if maze[0][i]==0:
        maze[0][i]=1
    else:
        break

#algorithm starts
for i in range(1,N):
    for j in range(1,N):
        if maze[i][j]==1:
            continue
        else:
            maze[i][j]+=maze[i-1][j]+maze[i][j-1]

print(maze[N-1][N-1])
```

**My output:**   `208`

---

I am confused, as to which one is the correct answer. Compared to `208`, `8512` seems to be an impractical answer for the aforementioned question. Can someone please help me out here?

Comment: Why don't you start with a much simpler array, one where you can calculate the answer by hand?

Comment: you're using `1` to identify 'impassible' squares AND using it to identify squares you have passed, after the first iteration this goes wrong!

Comment: I was looking into the algorithm of Dynamic Programming, and the first step was to insert 1 into the first row and column of the matrix.